# Prove that $2^{4n}+1$ cannot be a prime if $3|n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

$2^{4n}+1$ cannot be a prime if $3|n$ and $n>0$

My Try:
$$2^{12k}+1\equiv (-1)^{3k}+1 \equiv0\pmod{17}$$
So it divisible by $17$ for odd $k$. But how to complete the proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: $$ 16^{3k} +1 = (16^k+1)(16^{2k}-16^k+1).$$